# ブラウザなど外部ツールで得られる文字列をEmeditorで検索する方法

Tags: emeditor

たとえばFirefoxで見かけたウェブページ内のある文字列が、特定のテキストファイルに有るかどうか、検索したいときがあります。

それをEmeditorで検索する場合、その文字列をコピペし、Emeditorを起動してファイルを検索するしか方法はないでしょうか。

Firefoxをアクティブにしたまま文字列を範囲選択して、右クリックでコンテキストメニューを選ぶように、ショートカットでマクロなどが実行ができればよいのですが。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: これは、どちらかというと Firefox の質問になるのではないでしょうか? Firefox のタグを追加しておいた方が、回答が多くなると思います。Firefox から EmEditor を、コマンドラインとして選択文字列を追加して起動できれば、可能だと思います。EmEditor のコマンドラインの指定方法は、 http://www.emeditor.org/ja/howto_file_file_commandline.html を参考にしてください。